# Why does recursion return to first function?

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion

Sorry for asking a very basic question about an argument already talked about many times, I just can't figure out the answer. I tried searching the forum for already on-topic asked questions but didn't find an exact answer(or didn't understand it).

Why does this function print twice the numbers from i to 10 when called in different order?
Shouldn't it print out them in the same order? I keep hearing that this is how recursion works: every function calls in its code another identical one, just applied to a smaller domain until end condition is met. At this point it should go back (backtracking) to the original function; this is what I don't understand, why does it return(not intended as syntax call) to the main function.

```
void count(int i){
    if(i < 10){
          printf("%d\n", i);
          count(i + 1);
          printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Run your code through a debugger and single step into each line, you will find your answer ;)

Comment: Please don't mark questions SOLVED. Rather, accept the most helpful answer and leave the title as it was.

Comment: @EricLippert k, I'm new to the forum, didn't know the rules, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: No worries. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question for discussion of this point of usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A call with 7:

```
count(7)
    output 7
    count(8)
        output 8
        count(9)
            output 9
            count(10)
                end
            output 9
            end
        output 8
        end
    output 7
    end
```

Why shouldn´t it return?
Each function call will return sometimes, even if it is a recursive function.

Comment: A recursive function will return if it has a condition for abortion, otherwise you will have a *check the current tab's address* ;)

Comment: I see, so when the end condition is met, the last function is returned, then the penultimate and so on till the first one. For some reason, I thought each function one returned immediately after calling the next one, obviously wrong. All clear now.

Answer (score 2):

As with any function call, at the end, execution just starts back up at the next line:

```
 printf("%d\n", i);
 // into the function
 count(i + 1);
 // out of the function
 printf("%d\n", i);
```

The important thing to know is that the value of `i` doesn't get updated. They aren't the same variable. There are ten different 'versions' of `i`.

```
 printf("%d\n", i); // i is 3
 count(i + 1);
 printf("%d\n", i); // i is still three, but a version of the function just ran where i is 4
```

If you imagine just pasting the code in when you see count(i + 1), you get this when expanding count(8):

```
if(8 < 10){
      printf("%d\n", 8);
      count(8 + 1);
      printf("%d\n", 8);
}
```

Now paste:

```
if(8 < 10){
    printf("%d\n", 8);
    if(9 < 10){
        printf("%d\n", 9);
        count(9 + 1);
        printf("%d\n", 9);
    }
    printf("%d\n", 8);
}
```

And again:

```
if(8 < 10){
    printf("%d\n", 8);
    if(9 < 10){
        printf("%d\n", 9);
        if(10 < 10){
            // we'll never get here
        }
        printf("%d\n", 9);
    }
    printf("%d\n", 8);
}
```

This is the code that actually gets run. The 'old' values of `i` don't change. In the end you have 10 different `i` variables from all the different times your called the function.

Comment: All clear now, each function returns from the "smallest one" to the first one. That's what I didn't understand before.